# Resistor for connecting two 9-volt batteries to 12 V thermostat

Tags: voltage, batteries

I have two 9 V batteries connected in series to make an 18 V supply. I would like reduce it to 12 V for powering a thermostat.

So which resistor should I use?

Comment: A resistor is not suitable for this.  Even a linear voltage regulator would quickly result in dead batteries.  Why are you wanting to do this?  Figuring out a viable approach will depend on your actual goal.  Incidentally, most thermostats are 24 v AC, not 12 v DC.

Comment: To add to that a drop of 6V might require a buck converter/step down converter of some sort. Most linear voltage regulators will dissipate a lot of heat and won’t be efficient. The goal will in the end determine the approach.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a datasheet for the thermostat. Everyone is having to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a 12 volt battery for this. There are many sizes of 12 volt batteries.

As [Chris pointed out in his comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525076/i-would-like-connect-2-9volt-batteries-to-a-thermostat-but-it-needs-only-12-vol#comment1352430_525076):

> A resistor is not suitable for this. Even a linear voltage regulator would quickly result in dead batteries.

Comment: A "battery" isn't really the right solution.  So you get a bigger and more expensive one, maybe it lasts a month, but...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could be. Depends on the thermostat, and what he is doing. We have one here that the batteries simply back up the CMOS.

Answer (score -1):

9V batteries have a very small capacity. Most of them are 200mAh, some more expensive ones are 650mAh. It would be better to use a 12V, 18V, 24V charger. If you really want it to be remote, you will need a laptop battery at 19V, 3000 mAh or a car battery at 55 000 mAh. There are smaller car batteries, which are called motorcycle and electrical bike batteries. They can be 12 or 24V.

Comment: I think you mean "capacity" rather than "capacitance".

Comment: That was not really a reason to downvote my answer. I had forgotten how fun it is on these stack exchange sites...

Comment: I didn't downvote. You have no way of knowing who did - or why.

Comment: I did not downvote. I have not been looking for a reason. I do not hate you. I pointed out a minor terminology error in your post. You have made ten posts and I've checked through the other nine and there are no comments from me there. Can you show where I have been trying to find a reason? Are you a bit paranoid? Could you share your ways of knowing who downvoted a post?

Comment: As I explained, I've looked through all your previous nine questions and I have no comments on any of them so I can't see how you can accuse me of that. Do you have multiple accounts and I have commented on some of those? (Hmm. Previous comment disappeared while I wrote this.)

Comment: I was told to accept it's my fault this time and delete my comment. Therefore I apologise for being wrong.

Comment: Can we be friends now then? What got you so excited over such a minor issue? Why did you think I was after you?